# Selenium webscaping, Help wtih reducing the amount of bandwith

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

Im trying to reduce the amount of bandwith my program sends, I tried blocking images but it doesn't make much of a difference, Also I tried blocking certain requests but the website im trying to scrape detects it and I get blocked.

Do you guys know any other methods of reducing bandwith?